# Can I create a Filter rule on a TopicConfiguration for a cloudformation s3 bucket with an OR condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

For the sake of not duplicating code, I'd like to be able to create a filter rule with an OR condition... If either condition is true, then that satisfies the filter.

This is the original way that I'd like to avoid.

```
MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: myBuck

      NotificationConfiguration:        
        TopicConfigurations:
          - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'         
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: data/abcd/                                  
            Topic: myTopicArnGoesHere
          - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'         
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: data/efgh/  
            Topic: myTopicArnGoesHere
```

instead I'm hoping that there's a way to do something like this

```
NewBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: myBuck
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
      NotificationConfiguration:        
        TopicConfigurations:
          - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'         
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: data/abcd/                                  
                  OR
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: data/efgh/                                  
            Topic: myTopicArnGoesHere
```

Comment: Does it not work if you just remove that `OR` in the second example?

Comment: No.  Error: Cannot specify more than one prefix rule in a filter

Comment: Try naming them differently